# IBM Watson does not train the chatbot

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am on the IBM Watson Plus (Trial) plan. I just created a very simple assistant and added a Dialog skill. However, when I want to try my chatbot, I get the following message on top of the screen:

> Watson is training Results in the try out panel may not reflect the
> latest edits.

no matter what I type, I get this message:

> I didn't understand can you try again

I removed my Watson resource and created a new one however, I still have the same issue.
I also tried the "Customer Care Sample Skill" as well. However, still facing the same issue. Can you please help me?

Comment: Provide more details. Are you trying out a predefined dialog skill, if yes, what did you do? Provide details about your dialog nodes

Comment: Thanks! I just created an assistant and then added a Dialog skill with two intents (one for greeting and the second for asking a question about the order). I also added two nodes. The first node has a child node as well. The first node is associated with intent #greeting and its child node is associated with my second intent. The second node is for anything else (default). In other words, I just tried to copy a simple example that I found in many Watson toutrials online, nothing special. for some reason, the training process takes a long time. I don't know if there are any computational limits

Comment: And how did you test it? This seems to be something for the support, not about programming